# im trying to pull a mysql table row based on weather the column matches the POST however

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently attempting to echo a column based on if the row matches the needed row, its hard to explain but basically I want to be able to match a column from within the row to what is **POST** and **echo** another column in the row...

now if I manually add the variable `($game)` to the `WHERE sid = $game` it works, it will echo just fine, however when I attempt to do it like it is below it does not work...

```
 <?php
    $type = $_POST["type"];
    $game = $_POST["game"]; 
   $con = new mysqli("localhost","username","password!","database");
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo(mysqli_connect_error());
    }
        $data = $con->query("SELECT * FROM onlineservers WHERE sid='$game' ");
    if($type = 'command'){
       while($row = $data->fetch_assoc()){
       echo json_encode(array('command' => $row[cmd]));
       }
    }


?>
```

Comment: Change to "SELECT * FROM onlineservers WHERE sid=" . $game

Just to add to that... You use a . to join two strings together. You can't use $variable in the middle of a string because PHP doesn't know if you wanted to type a dollar sign or use a variable.

Comment: Try this WHERE sid= ".$game."

Comment: If I do that I get the error "Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object"

Comment: `$type = 'command'` is not comparing, it is setting.

Comment: When `WHERE sid = $game` works either `$game` must be quoted or an integer. Use error checking to see what is happening. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php You also are open to SQL injections.

Comment: Also why even bother setting up the DB connection and executing the query if the `type` isn't `command`?